# Creating a Dynamic Select Statement from 2 databases on the same server

Tags: c#, ado.net

Can someone improve on my method for creating union select views from 2 databases located within the same server in C#, here is the code for the method:

```
public override DataSet GetDynamicReportData(string strSQL) {

        var sbSQL = new StringBuilder(strSQL);
        var finalQueryStr = new StringBuilder(strSQL);

        sbSQL.Replace("SELECT DISTINCT ", "");

        var iamNEAS3 =
            new StringBuilder(" UNION SELECT DISTINCT ");

        var queryColumns = sbSQL.ToString().Split(',');

        for (var i = 0; i <= queryColumns.Length - 1; i++) {

            iamNEAS3.Append(queryColumns[i]);

            if (i < queryColumns.Length - 1) {
                iamNEAS3.Append(", ");
            } else if (i == queryColumns.Length - 1) {

                var appendMagic =
                    queryColumns[i].Replace(
                        "From [dbo].[vw_Classified_ApplicationsFiles]",
                        "FROM [project_phoenix].[dbo].[vw_Classified_ApplicationFiles]")

                iamNEAS3.Append(appendMagic);

                // Systematic removal; thank you!
                iamNEAS3.Replace(queryColumns[i], "");
            }
        }

        finalQueryStr.Append(iamNEAS3);

        return DALDynamicReport.GetData(finalQueryStr.ToString());
    }
```

Now it receives a string parameter where

```
strSQL = "Select Distinct [Row1], [Row2], [Row3], [Row4] From [project_mongoose].[dbo].[vw_Classified_ApplicationsFiles] where [Row2] <= 200".
```

I know my programming skills are limited, but is there a way to not code this by hand like I did?

Comment: Where that `strSQL` come from? Trusted and secured code/configuration or user input (or easy to tamper configuration)? Hmmmmm did you try with a regex?

Comment: Passed as a string parameter from another project Web API

Comment: Is it _secure_? If you can't assume it's secure then you should never ever manually build (or accept) SQL strings.

Comment: Not so sure about being sure, but how can I parameterized it?

Comment: You may use, for example, a Query Object.

Comment: But the string is received as is, (demonstrated by second code piece)

Comment: Yes, I mean that if possible you should not receive a SQL string but an object. It will make code more robust (not string splitting and blind replacements) and it won't be open that easily to SQL injection (assuming caller is not secure or does not properly validate user input).

Comment: You are adding the last column and then removing it?

Comment: :)  I really don't remember the logic behind that - got to do with appendMagic thing

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should improve is to split this method into two methods, one for parsing the input string and one for  building a new query. Doing both in the same method isn't a good practice.

This means that the first method should return a collection of columns that the other one consumes.

Comment: Ok, I can see that working, but I also have to ensure that views return exactly the same columns